# Glassmapper Set outputHeightWidth = true by default

Tags: glass-mapper

I have a requirement where I need to display the image height and width tags on images. This is also a performance ranking factor for Google Lighthouse. By default, this is set to false in Glassmapper as follows:

```
        //
    // Summary:
    //     Renders an image allowing simple page editor support
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   model:
    //     The model that contains the image field
    //
    //   field:
    //     A lambda expression to the image field, should be of type Glass.Mapper.Sc.Fields.Image
    //
    //   parameters:
    //     Image parameters, e.g. width, height
    //
    //   isEditable:
    //     Indicates if the field should be editable
    //
    //   outputHeightWidth:
    //     Indicates if the height and width attributes should be outputted when rendering
    //     the image
    //
    // Type parameters:
    //   T:
    //     The model type
    public virtual HtmlString RenderImage<T>(T model, Expression<Func<T, object>> field, object parameters = null, bool isEditable = false, bool outputHeightWidth = false)
    {
        return new HtmlString(GlassHtml.RenderImage(model, field, parameters, isEditable, outputHeightWidth));
    }
```

While I can add the following to each of my image renderings, I would prefer to default this to true for all images so none get missed (we have a lot of image renderings across so many pages and need to maximize our SEO):

```
@Html.Glass().RenderImage(panel.GlassItem, x => x.My_Image, isEditable: true, outputHeightWidth: true )
```

I have a foundational project for Glassmapper, but am unsure where and how is the best place to default this setting to true (ex. App_Start > GlassMapperScCustom.cs)

Answer (score 4):

What you can do is replacing default `Glass.Mapper.Sc.GlassHtml` with your own implementation that will always use `true` for `outputHeightWidth` parameter like:

```
public class CustomGlassHtml : Glass.Mapper.Sc.GlassHtml
{
    public CustomGlassHtml(ISitecoreService sitecoreService) : base(sitecoreService)
    {
    }

    public override string RenderImage<T>(T model, Expression<Func<T, object>> field, object parameters = null, bool isEditable = false, bool outputHeightWidth = false, string imgElementTemplate = "<img src={2}{0}{2} {1}/>")
    {
        return base.RenderImage(model, field, parameters, isEditable, true, imgElementTemplate);
    }
}
```

Now you need to create your own `IGlassHtmlFactory` implementation like:

```
public class CustomGlassHtmlFactory : IGlassHtmlFactory
{
    public CustomGlassHtmlFactory(IDependencyResolver dependencyResolver)
    {
    }

    public IGlassHtml GetGlassHtml(ISitecoreService sitecoreService)
    {
        return new CustomGlassHtml(sitecoreService);
    }
}
```

and finally register your own factory in Glass dependency resolver. There are multiple options depending on Sitecore version. In Sitecore 10 you should be able to add processor to `glassMapper.createResolver` pipeline:

```
<glassMapper.createResolver help="Processors should derive from Glass.Mapper.Sc.Pipelines.CreateResolver.CreateResolverProcessor">
  <!-- Add any changes to the standard resolver here. -->
</glassMapper.createResolver>
```

Something like this should do the trick:

```
public class SetCustomFactory : CreateResolverProcessor
{
    public override void Process(CreateResolverPipelineArgs args)
    {
        args.DependencyResolver.GlassHtmlFactory = new CustomGlassHtmlFactory(args.DependencyResolver);
    }
}
```